# What's an example of an ExtraNonce2 value that would be considered invalid?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, nonce, stratum

I've been learning about mining as part of a pool and using the Stratum protocol to submit completed work back to a pool -- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Stratum_mining_protocol .  There is this parameter, "ExtraNonce2," a value that the miner keeps changing.  Could someone tell me a scenario where a pool worker submits a nonce that correctly hashes the data it was given according to the difficulty, but it submits an "ExtraNonce2" value that causes the mining pool to reject the submission?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that would ever happen?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a scenario. The ExtraNonce2 is part of the data that is hashed. So if a miner finds a valid nonce, he must also have the corresponding ExtraNonce2 that is part of the data that is hashed in order to produce a valid block hash.